# Why does my custom Amazon EC2 AMI have limited instance type options?

Tags: amazon-ec2

The Basic 64-bit Amazon Linux AMI has the following instance type options available:

- Micro
- Large
- Extra-Large
- High-Memory Extra Large

... etc

I booted up this AMI as a micro type, made customizations, shut it down, detached the volume, took a snapshot, and registered my own custom AMI:
ec2-register –snapshot [snapshot_id] –description "my description" –name "my name" –kernel aki-427d952b

That worked. HOWEVER, when I try to create an instance from my custom AMI, only the following instance types are available:

- Micro
- Small
- High-CPU Medium

... which coincidentally are the same instance types available if you try to boot up the **32-bit** Amazon image.

Why are the available instance types of my custom image varying from the available instance types of the image I based it off of?

Comment: so you selected a 64-bit instance and they are only allowing you to launch the AMI as a 32-bit instance?

Comment: I'm not sure if the problem is specific to 32-bit vs 64-bit, but am just making an observation about the association between default AMIs and their corresponding instance types. It seems as though if I customize the default 64-bit Amazon Linux AMI, I should be able to boot that custom AMI under any of the same instance types available under the default 64-bit Amazon Linux AMI. But instead, it only lets me boot with an instance type that would typically be associated with the default 32-bit Amazon Linux AMI

Answer (score 2):

When you register the image, make sure to include an explicit

-a x86_64

Without this, you let the Black Box of Amazon's back end decide which architecture to use.  Apparently it defaults to 32bit, or guessed wrong in your case.